# Translation of phrase from "Le Petit Prince"

Tags: translation-check, english-to-latin-translation

There is an awesome quote in the brilliant book "Le Petit Prince" by Antoine de Saint-Exupéry that is commonly translated to English as "what is essential is invisible to the eye" or simple "the essential is invisible to the eyes". I'm trying to translate it to Latin for a birthday card and the best that I could was "*quod est per se invisibilis oculum*". It is right? Does anyone suggest a better translation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Latin translation of *Le petit prince* has been published: *Regulus, vel Pueri soli sapiunt*, trans. Auguste Haury (Paris: Fernand Hazan, editeur, 1961). In it, the line is translated as follows:

> Quae plurimi sunt, oculis cerni non possunt.
>
> ('What is worth the most cannot be seen with the eyes.')

Comment: "Quod ceteros celavi, hoc est; est autem simplicissimum: animo tantum bene cernimus. Quae plurimi sunt, oculis cerni non possunt."